# Drupal 8 - Admin - Show only content for that role

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-roles

I have a problem
In the Admin, even if you assign privileges to the roles, defining what contentypes they can manage and which not, when a person who only has access to 1 type of content, when accessing the ADMIN, sees ALL the contents.

Yes, only can edit the ones that I have defined in the privilege zone, but he can see all the contents

In addition, he can also FILTER for all types of content using contetype select dropdown in search zone

Is there any way that if I have created a user who has privileges to edit and view the contentype "OFFICES" do not see the rest of contentypes, nor in the listings, if in the select filter etc?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

By default Drupal doesn't provide any permissions set to control view permission for individual node. There is a single permission set 'view any content', which control the view permission of nodes for all user roles.

I would suggest you to look for contributed modules like [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access), [Node Access Grants](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_access_grants) and [Node view permission](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_view_permissions) to get the things done for you.

If you choose the Content Access a guide is also available here https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/drupal-8-restricting-content/.